# In a Xamarin Master-Detail MVVM setup, how to fire off an event from a Child View's View Model and have it caught by the Parent View's View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

**TLDR;** Since Xamarin Forms doesn't support Routed Events, is there an alternative pattern in Xamarin Forms to do what I'm asking here.  What I need to do is fire off an event from a Child View's View Model and have it caught by the Parent View's View Model.

---

In my setup, I have a page Root Page that is a [MasterDetail](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/) page:

```
public partial class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
```

I set the master to `MainMenuPage` and the child to `MyChildPage1`.

```
var rootPage = new RootPage
{
    Master = new MainMenuPage(),
    Detail = new MyChildPage1()
};
App.MainPage = rootPage;
```

I assign a ViewModel to all three of them:

```
rootPage.BindingContext = new RootPageViewModel();
rootPage.Master.BindingContext = new MainMenuPageViewModel();
rootPage.Detail.BindingContext = new MyChildPage1ViewModel();
```

There's a button in `MainMenuPage`.  When you click it, it fires an `ICommand` on `MainMenuPageViewModel`. This is the normal MVVM / Binding stuff.

In `MainMenuPageViewModel` in the `ICommand`, I want to fire off something. (Routed Event?) And I want this event caught by `RootPage`.  `RootPage` will then change a property on the ViewModel bound to `rootPage.Detail` (how?)

Comment: Create an event in MainMenuPageViewModel ans subscribe to it from RootPageViewModel. Alternatively you can use MessagingCenter

Comment: What about something with BindableProperty (use them like dependency properties)?

Comment: Using MessagingCenter for this feels like, well, an indictment against MVVM in Xamarin. Is there nothing else?

Comment: As I said - event might work. You can use bindable properties too and try to set them for parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessagingCenter

[Xamarin Messaging Center](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)